# How to change the color of the letters when you search

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, search, searchbar

How do I change the color of the letters while I search?

```js
function searchInputMbl() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  
  hideIt = document.getElementById("hide-item-mb");
  input = document.getElementById("searchInputMbl");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("gl-search-complete-mb");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
      hideIt.style.display = "block";
      ul.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
      hideIt.style.display = "none";
      ul.style.display = "block";
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Like Google Search? While searching the text gets bold as we enter the value in input

Comment: like apple website search ,thanks for your answer

Comment: Any [of these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+highlight+search) help?